После перезагрузки страницы отображает не ту страницу, которая перегружалась
Админка на React, Redux, React-router. Компоненты доступные после авторизации, обернуты в ProtectedRoute. На /panel лэйаут. После выбора нужного компонента в лэйауте получается адрес типа /panel/component. Все в принципе работает, но при первом ручном обновлении страницы по адресу /panel/component (разумеется когда мы уже авторизованы) отображает /panel, а при повторном обновлении (по факту уже обновляем /panel) показывает /panel/component. Уже пару часов потратил, но не могу понять что не так. Просвятите, плиз.
Ниже код ProtectedRoute.
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function ProtectedRoute(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const location = useLocation();
  const { isAuth, isAuthCompleted } = useSelector((store) => store.auth);

  if (!isAuthCompleted) return null;

  if (!isAuth) return <Navigate to='/login' state={{ from: location, replace: true }} />;

  if (isAuth) return children;
}

